# Unable to admin login due to CAPTCHA validation error: unknown CAPTCHA session ID. Contact the site administrator if this problem persists

Tags: captcha

When I try to admin login, I'm getting following error. Screencap attached.
Is it possible to disable google recaptcha from database?
[image]

Comment: Are you experiencing this error in a production or local environment?

Comment: Drush can uninstall modules or change configurations.

Comment: I'm getting this error from production server.

Comment: Since this is a production environment, I would highly reckon you to clone the environment in your localhost, disable the captcha module using drush or directly from the database or from the Drupal backend. For the third option access to the backend can be gained by executing drush uli. Once you have the access to the backend see the log messages to find out what exactly is the error.